# Push notifications (home badges) supported by PhoneGap?

Tags: mobile, cordova, push-notification, push

I have read the documentation from phonegap saying its support some push notifications features http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/37159628/Notifications 
May I know whether its possible to have "home badge" push notifications using PhoneGap?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you have come right yet but this might help you with android.

[Link to android push notification](https://github.com/saileshmittal/phonegap-system-notification-plugin/tree/master/android-statusbar-notificaion)

I havent tried this myself but i am looking for a home badge method for the iphone using phonegap

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with the [Cordova Push Notifications Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin).

This plugin provides you with a convenient callback for push notifications, where you can set the application icon badge accordingly, e.g.:

```
//push notifications callback function
function onNotificationAPN (event) {
    //handle push message
    if (event.badge) //a badge number is provided in the push message
    {
        //set the application icon badge number accordingly
        pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, errorHandler, event.badge);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but that's for iOS only. So far there seems to be no support for Android, of course, they 'only' have 86% of the market share...